# .NET function does not retrieve the proper data

Tags: c#, .net, database, asp.net-web-api, datacontext

I've created a methods in my SituationController to obtain a list of the Situations, in a JSON format. The method is called GetSituations.

```
namespace Amaz.API.Controllers
{
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SituationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IVVRepository _repo;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public SituationController(IVVRepository repo, IMapper mapper)
        {
           
            _mapper = mapper;
            _repo = repo;

        }

        [HttpGet("{UserId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSituations (int UserId)
        {
            var currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

            var situationreturn = await _repo.GetSituations(UserId);

            if (situationreturn == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(situationreturn);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSituation (int id)
        {
            // if (id != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
            // return Unauthorized();

            var situationreturn = await _repo.GetSituation(id);

            if (situationreturn == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(situationreturn);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutSituation(SituationDto SituationDto)
        {
            var SituationToCreate = _mapper.Map<Situation>(SituationDto);
            _repo.Add(SituationToCreate);
            await _repo.SaveAll();

            return NoContent();
        }


        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSituation(int id, SituationDto SituationDto)
        {
            var situation = await _repo.GetSituation(id);
            _mapper.Map(SituationDto, situation);
            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSituation (int id)
        {            
              var SituationFromRepo = await _repo.GetSituation(id);
              _repo.Delete(SituationFromRepo);
              return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

While in the repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Situation>> GetSituations (int UserId)
{
    var messages = _context.Messages.AsQueryable();
    return (IEnumerable<Situation>)messages;
}
```

And in the interface of the repository:

```
Task<IEnumerable<Situation>> GetSituations (int UserId);
```

But for any reason, it is not working as expected. When using Postman to test the API `http://localhost:5000/api/Situation/1` the return is only one of the situations:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Limpieza",
    "isMain": false,
    "userId": 1,
    "isApproved": true,
    "item1": 0,
    "item2": 1,
    "item3": 2,
    "item4": 3,
    "item5": 4,
    "item6": 5,
    "item7": 6,
    "item8": 7,
    "item9": 8,
    "item10": 9,
    "item11": 10,
    "item12": 11,
    "item13": 12,
    "item14": 13,
    "item15": 14,
    "item16": 15,
    "item17": 16,
    "item18": 17,
    "item19": 18,
    "item20": 19
}
```

But, really it should return all the situations that are stored in the database. Why it does not work?

Comment: Hi, does it give an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two HttpGet methods with the same routes. Only one of them will get hit when you call that route and right now it's hitting the GetSituation endpoint instead of the GetSituations endpoint when you use `http://localhost:5000/api/Situation/1`. You need to add a specific route to at least one of them. You can use attribute routing for that:

```
[HttpGet("{UserId}")]
[Route("all")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSituations (int UserId)
```

Then try to hit this endpoint: `http://localhost:5000/api/Situation/all/1` to retrieve data from GetSituations.

Continue to use this endpoint: `http://localhost:5000/api/Situation/1` to retrieve data from GetSituation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's still not working. As I defined the controller:

```
        [Route("api/[controller]/all")]
        [HttpGet]
         public async Task<IActionResult> GetSituations ()
        {
            var currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

            var situationstoreturn = await _repo.GetSituations();

            if (situationstoreturn == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(situationstoreturn);
        }
```

And the function in the interface repository

```
    Task<IEnumerable<Situation>> GetSituations ();
```

and the repository:

```
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Situation>> GetSituations ()
    {
        var Situation = _context.Situations.ToListAsync();
        return await Situation;
    }
```

The outcome with `http://localhost:5000/api/Situation/all` is:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "id": [
            "The value 'all' is not valid."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|fafb39a-479332ff01211120."
}
```

It was supposed to work, but still it fails...I can't get the clue...

Comment: You've already defined this route on your class [Route("api/[controller]")] so all actions within the class will be prefixed with that route. Therefore, you don't need to prefix the route attribute on the method with "api/[controller]" again. You can just add [Route("all")] to the method.

Comment: Nothing happens: http://localhost:5000/api/Situation/all/ results in: {
    "errors": {
        "id": [
            "The value 'all' is not valid."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|6e318df2-469ed81893adc4fa."
}

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is the state of the art. Here the Controller:

```
namespace Amaz.API.Controllers
{
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SituationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IVVRepository _repo;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public SituationController(IVVRepository repo, IMapper mapper)
        {
           
            _mapper = mapper;
            _repo = repo;

        }
        //We pick UP all the situations with GET
        [Route("all")]
        [HttpGet]
         public async Task<IActionResult> GetSituations (int UserId)
        {
            //Esto debería devolver el usuario
            var currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

            var situationstoreturn = await _repo.GetSituations(UserId);

            if (situationstoreturn == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(situationstoreturn);
        } 

        //GET only one situation
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSituation (int id)
        {
            // if (id != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
            // return Unauthorized();

            var situationreturn = await _repo.GetSituation(id);

            if (situationreturn == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(situationreturn);
        }
        //Añadimos situación POST
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutSituation(SituationDto SituationDto)
        {
            var SituationToCreate = _mapper.Map<Situation>(SituationDto);
            _repo.Add(SituationToCreate);
            await _repo.SaveAll();

            return NoContent();
        }

        //Update Situacion PUT
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSituation(int id, SituationDto SituationDto)
        {
            var situation = await _repo.GetSituation(id);
            _mapper.Map(SituationDto, situation);
            return NoContent();
        }
        //Delete Situation DEL
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSituation (int id)
        {            
              var SituationFromRepo = await _repo.GetSituation(id);
              _repo.Delete(SituationFromRepo);
              return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

And the repository is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Situation>> GetSituations(int UserId)
{
    var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == UserId);
    var Situation = _context.Situations.ToListAsync();
    return await Situation;

}
```

Unfortunately when I give the API this call with postman:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/Situation/all/
```

I obtain:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "id": [
            "The value 'all' is not valid."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|6e318df2-469ed81893adc4fa."
}
```

So I think that is not possible to obtain an array with all the situations given an UserId